# Run Gradle task on the basis of Build Variant

Tags: gradle, build-variant, dokka

I have been struggling on this for past 2 days. There are several solutions on stack overflow which didn't work for me.
I am trying to ignore gradle task for prod environment.
To execute my task i.e. dokkaHtml on build, I am using this command -

> tasks.named('preBuild') { finalizedBy(dokkaHtml) }

Is there a way to disable **dokkaHtml** task when running on different build variant(eg - ignore the task for production builds)?

Comment: Which task do you want to ignore? `preBuild`? I'm afraid it's not possible, because it runs some checks, etc. that are necessary to build your variant. Also, what do you mean by "prod environment"? Is it the `release` build type?

Comment: I want to ignore dokkaHtml. Right now it will run after pre build everytime, but I dont want it to be executed in production environment i.e for different build variant. I have 3 product flavors in my gradle file - dev, test and prod.

Answer (score 1):

I am checking the current product flavor and based on the result, enabling the gradle task. This solution is working for me -

```
def getCurrentFlavor() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern
    if( tskReqStr.contains( "assemble" ) )
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )
    if( matcher.find() )
        return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    else
        return ""
}

var currentFlavor = getCurrentFlavor().toString()
//disable dokka for prod environment
if(!currentFlavor.contains("production")){
    tasks.preBuild.finalizedBy(dokkaHtml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to connect dokka task to a flavor-specific `preBuild`, so in your case, it would be something like this:

```
tasks.named('preDevDebugBuild') { finalizedBy(dokkaHtml) }
tasks.named('preDevReleaseBuild') { finalizedBy(dokkaHtml) }
tasks.named('preTestDebugBuild') { finalizedBy(dokkaHtml) }
tasks.named('preTestReleaseBuild') { finalizedBy(dokkaHtml) }
```

This way you omit dokka for the prod flavor.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though, the solution looks promising, but it didn't work for me. Gradle couldn't find task named- preDevDebugBuild.

Comment: What if you wrap this and put inside `afterEvaluate` block?

Comment: Adding this will not be able to figure out the current build variant, I am building into. I have found the other solution wherein I am calling the method to get the build variant and enabling the gradle task based on the value. Let me add the solution.